# Java. Узнать тип неинициализированной ссылки

Tags: java

Объявляем ссылки:

```
Wall wall;
User user;
```

Как узнать тип ссылки wall и user? Возможно?

Из того, что нашел:

[Динамическая идентификация типа данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85#Java)
. Данный вариант не подходит, так как требует наличия объекта

Comment: Это игра, в которой надо угадать язык?

Comment: @kff может стоит оформить это как ответ? Перевести содержательную часть ответа и привести ссылку для более детального разбора, кто захочет.

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению, нет. С точки зрения виртуальной машины объявлений переменных нет, есть только значения. Поскольку нет значения, то нельзя и проверить тип. В самом языке тоже нет конструкций, которые могут во время компиляции что-то сделать в зависимости от типа.

Answer (score 1):

Совсем неинициализированной никак нельзя. Вряд ли Ваша программа будет даже компилироваться.
Если под неинициализированная подразумевается `null`, то можно воспользоваться overloading, если не нужно какое-то общее решение:

```
public void commonMethod(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o);
}

public void method(User user) {
    System.out.print("User: ");
    commonMethod(user);
}

public void method(Wall wall) {
    System.out.print("Wall: ");
    commonMethod(wall);
}

public void test() {
    User user = null;
    Wall wall = null;

    method(user); // Напечатает User: null
    method(wall); // Напечатает Wall: null
}
```

Comment: а если `method(null)`?

Comment: @Grundy  тогда `method(Object o)` добавить и вызывать так `method((Object)null)` Вообще `null` надо приводить к одному из поддерживаемых типов

Comment: то есть, вот эта строчка `method(null)` даже не скомпилируется? кстати, если все равно надо приводить к типу, то _method(Object o)_ не нужен же

Comment: @Grundy Да. Не компилируется. Возникает неоднозначность. Любой из методов может принимать null.

Comment: @Grundy Может нужен, может не нужен. Кто его знает, это зависит от задачи. Если два типа поддерживаем, то не нужен. А если первое, второе и особый случай - `х.з. что это ваще такое` (как троичная логика SQL), то наверное нужен.